# Getting relative path inside a custom component

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, navigation, uri

I've got a custom component project and I'm referring from another project.

I need to navigate between pages of the custom component, so I'm using this code:

```
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
frame.Navigate(new Uri("/CustomComponent;component/Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Now, provided that my custom component has a structure like this one:

```
Root Folder
       \_ Page.xaml
       \_ Folder A
                 \_ BaseClass.cs
       \_ Folder B
                 \_ Folder C
                           \_ Class.cs (extends BaseClass)
                           \_ Page2.xaml
```

I'd like to call a method inside `Class.cs` which returns a string that allows me to navigate to `Page2.xaml` using the navigation code that I posted.

So, this method should return

> /CustomComponent;component/Folder B/Folder C/Page2.xaml

(the `/CustomComponent;component/` is optional, but I need it to return the correct folder structure to navigate to the page)

I've been trying using `Directory` class but the `GetCurrentDirectory()` method returns and absolute path which points to the app's installation folder, and I need it to be a relative path which follows the component's structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function to get an absolute path to the calling function:

```
    public static string GetFilePathLoc([CallerFilePath] string filePath = "")
    {
        return filePath;
    }
```

You can post process to just extract the relative part, for example by creating a RootClass and calling the GetFilePathLoc from it and in Class1:

```
    public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string GetResourceFilePath()
    {
        string assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        assemblyName = assemblyName.Substring(0, assemblyName.IndexOf(','));


        string myFilePath = GetRealClassPath();

        //If base class is in the root directory, this could just be replaced by string projectFolder = GetFilePathLoc();
        string projectFolder = RootClass.GetPath();

        //Remove the "absolute part" of the path
        myFilePath = myFilePath.Substring(projectFolder.Length);
         myFilePath=myFilePath.Replace('\\', '/');

        return "/" + assemblyName + ",component/" + myFilePath;
    }

    protected abstract string GetRealClassPath();

    protected static string GetFilePathLoc([CallerFilePath] string filePath = "")
    {
        int indexFileName= filePath.LastIndexOf('\\');
        return filePath.Substring(0, indexFileName+1);
    }
}


public class Class1 :BaseClass
{
    protected override string GetRealClassPath()
    {
        return GetFilePathLoc(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question because I forgot to say that my class extends another class. So, adding this code to the `BaseClass` will make it return the path to that class, even if it's called from the derived one. Do I have to copy and paste this code in each subclass to make it work?

Comment: the only code which need to be on class1 is the GetFilePathLoc() call. I modified my example to put most of the code in BaseClass

Comment: I still can't get it working. When run from a class which has this path `plugins/widgets/PRIVATE/Class.cs` it returns `/Component;component/IVATE\Class.cs`

Comment: Fixed (Added a part to remove the file name in GetFilePathLoc and replace \ by / in GetResourceFilePath), I tested it this time so it should work :), Just make sure that you put RootClass (or BaseClass if you used string projectFolder = GetFilePathLoc();) in the root of the library